# Surface Area of a Superellipsoid

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

We know the surface area of a supersphere (x^n+y^n+z^n=1) can be easily obtained using the gamma function ([here is the discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80243/surface-area-of-superellipsoid-dice)). But what happens when we consider a superellipsoid ($x^m +y^n+z^p=1;  m \neq n\neq p $), or more generally for the implicit function $(x/a)^m +(y/b)^n+(z/c)^p=1;  a \neq b\neq c; m \neq n\neq p $

Comment: There probably is no closed-form formula.

Comment: @Matt F.: Depends of what is meant by "closed-form" formula. Any formula will contain some integral. But Gamma function (for the sphere) is also an integral, is not it?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I would argue that the Gamma function in the formulas for spheres is just there to give a common expression for both, odd and even dimensions. You do not need it for, say, even dimensions. Here you can give a closed form using only factorials.

Comment: Some of the references I give in [this 2 June 2007 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sci.math/Sahadevan%7Csort:date/sci.math/MBOvcdAaa-0/JipMqumENSQJ) may be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

The surface area of an $n$-dimensional ellipsoid is expressed in terms of hyperelliptic integrals, see  [SURFACE AREA AND CAPACITY OF ELLIPSOIDS IN n
DIMENSIONS](http://nzjm.math.auckland.ac.nz/images/b/b3/Surface_area_and_capacity_of_ellipsoids_in_n_dimensions.pdf) by
Garry J. Tee

In dimension 3, they are elliptic integrals, and the result is due to Legendre. The paper also mentions approximate formulas.

For $n\neq m\neq p$ one can write the integrals but they have no standard name: [Surface area of an $\ell_p$ unit ball?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234314/surface-area-of-an-ell-p-unit-ball)

Comment: I have tried to solve with the article you have suggested, can you find out how to employ the integral for different exponents?